# Blink 3 LEDs at 1 Hz with a Power up ON Time Delay

Tags: arduino

I am very new to Arduino!

I am struggling to create an Arduino program that would blink 3 LEDs with 1 Hz rate with an initial ON time delay for the 2nd and the 3rd LED.

When the Arduino is switched ON the 1 st LED should start blinking at 1 Hz normally without any initial delay.

The second LED should start blinking at 1 Hz frequency after about 0.66 seconds behind the 1st LED.

Similarly, the 3rd LED should begin its 1 Hz oscillation 0.66 behind the 2nd LED.

Once these initial start-up delays are accomplished for the 2nd and the 3rd LEDs, all the 3 LEDs should go on blinking infinitely, until power is switched OFF.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Are all three LEDs in phase at the end of powerup and delay or do they still have a 660mS phase shift?  Fix your question and show a diagram of the expected behavior.

Comment: start by blinking one LED  ............ refer to the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example code

Comment: also do some research .... if you did, you would have become aware of https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: If I understand you correctly, "things" will happen at t=0, 0.5, 0.66, 1.0, 1.16, 1.33, 1.5, 1.66, 1.83 etc. (basically at  0 + n*0.5, 0.66 + n*0.5 and 1.33 + n*0.5) seconds. The simplest way for a beginner is to use the delay function and figure out what to do at those times (burns all your CPU cycles so it's horrible progamming, but..)

Comment: @Jack Creasey, they must continue to have 660ms phase shift as long as  the Arduino is powered. I think this should automatically happen, since their frequencies are identical.

Comment: Here's the diagram with the expected waveform: https://www.homemade-circuits.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/3-led.jpg

Comment: @SwagatamMajumdar that diagram does not match the description. - you have 1/3 second delay not 2/3 second (or perhaps you have 0.5Hz instead of 1Hz.)

Comment: OK, let's assume it's 0.5 Hz, I can adjust the parameters afterwards, for me the main challenge is getting those initial one time delays for the 2nd and the 3rd LEDs, or it could be 3 individually adjustable frequency AMVs with individually adjustable one time start up delay.

Answer (score 0):

something like this perhaps.

```
const char* p="11102231546" + 5;
int i=-5;

for(;;){
    output(p[i]&7);
    i=(i+1)%6;
    delay(166);
    }
```

where output is a function that takes the bits given it and sets the corresponding outputs high or low.

the LED pattern changes every 1/6 seconds and after the first 5 steps it enters a repeating pattern

Comment: Thank you so much, so will this give the expected results, if I compile it?

Comment: it's untested,.so maybe.